ASP.NET MVC 5 - Startup not running
I have two ASP.NET MVC 5 applications - one if I put a breakpoint at:
Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)

This breakpoint is hit, and the app runs fine - the other it just skips it and loads the web page. The trouble is Startup loads ConfigureAuth and that loads the configuration settings for authentication, so I was trying to fix why LoginPath wasn't working.
I have read a number of articles about issues with Global.asax and IIS. If it runs on one solution but not the other, and Global.asax is hitting a breakpoint on both solutions - then it must be something else - I have tried all the usual suspects (rebuilding, clean, restart VS...) but still the same problem.
Any ideas?

Tracked it down.
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

was missing - installed that and it ran perfectly :-)
